# Why can't I play mp3 files in java

Tags: command-line, java, mp3

I am making a study guide in java to help me learn Japanese, but I have been having a hard time getting it to speak Japanese to me. Espeak did not work, so I used [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13339421/java-download-text-to-speech-from-google-translate) to get a .mp3 file and installed mpg123 to play the file. This works fine it the terminal, but it can't get it to play in java.

My code:

```
String command="mpg123 "+dir+"/Xubuntu\\ Apps/Study\\ guide/Japanese/sounds/あう.mp3";
        System.out.println(command);
        try {Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);} catch (IOException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
```

The output

```
mpg123 /home/myuser/Documents/Xubuntu\ Apps/Study\ guide/Japanese/sounds/あう.mp3
```

I hear no sound, but when I copy/paste the command in the terminal, it works fine.

Why isn't playing in java?

Comment: Why it should be in Java?

Comment: @Braiam The rest of the study guide is already written in java. I am just trying to add functionality

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to use an Embed code for playing the song then you can use this code ,:)

Source: http://java-demos.blogspot.hu/2012/11/java-code-to-play-mp3-file.html

Code for playing an MP3 song in Java:

```
import javax.media.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class AudioPlay {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {

        // Take the path of the audio file from command line
        File f = new File(args[0]);

        // Create a Player object that realizes the audio
        final Player p = Manager.createRealizedPlayer(f.toURI().toURL());

        // Start the music
        p.start();

        // Create a Scanner object for taking input from cmd
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

        // Read a line and store it in st
        String st = s.nextLine();

        // If user types 's', stop the audio
        if (st.equals("s")) {
            p.stop();
        }
    }
}
```

> **Explanation**:
>
> **Player** is an interface in the **javax.media** package. As you cannot create an object for an interface directly some class
>   implementing it is written and it's object is used. Manager is such a
>   class that does the thing.
>
> There are several states in which a Player will be. They are
>
> **UNREALIZED**: Meaning, the player knows nothing about what it has to do (about the media)
>
> **REALIZING**: Meaning, the player is realizing it's world (determining resources) necessary to do the job (playing the file)
>
> **REALIZED**: Meaning, the player gets its resources to play the file and will also have some info about the type of the media etc.
>
> **PREFETCHING**: It's getting ready now, it is knowing how could it play the file.
>
> **PREFETCHED**: Now, it knows how to play the media. It can fire now.
>
> **START**: Start the music, starts playing the file.
>
> We have created a realized player, it does not mean that the UNREALIZED, REALIZING steps are skipped instead they are automatically done. The method `createRealizedPlayer(URL url)` takes a URL which points to the media file. For getting the URL object from a File object, you can use `toURL()` method in the `java.io.File` class, as it is deprecated we've called `toURI()` method which returns `java.net.URI` object and then the `toURL()` method in it.The user also needs to stop the music, so input is taken from the user.
>
> Output however cannot be shown, you'll have to try it, remember that when executing the program give the complete path of the audio file otherwise `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` will arise. The command might look like this:

```
java AudioPlay "Path/to/file.mp3"
```

Credit Goes to [Java Demo](http://java-demos.blogspot.com/2012/11/java-code-to-play-mp3-file.html)